# Scroll overflowed content on iPad with VoiceOver enabled

Tags: html, ipad, scroll, accessibility, voiceover

I have a website where we have a div with fixed width and height. We set the overflow of the div to be scroll. However, this causes problems on the iPad with VoiceOver enabled. Usually with VoiceOver enabled, a three-fingered gesture scrolls the content, but in this case it refuses to scroll. I tried the -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch css rule, but it did not work. Are there any other technical suggestions?

I know that we can enter traditional gestures by double-tapping and then doing the normal gesture, but I would prefer to integrate with VoiceOver naturally.

Comment: If you have content in that container selected, can you swipe right (next) and get to everything? You might be thinking a bit too visually, a voiceover user may not know that container is scrollable.